# How can I partition a MySql table for use with 90 day rotating partitions?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I want to create a partitioned table which is going to be filled with hundreds of millions of records. Using partitioning how can I have a particular day's records go into one partition, then the next day's in another, etc.. Then after ninety odd days I can delete old data from the oldest partition.

I tried this declaration (the hash function uses a modulo against the amount of partitions to calculate which partition gets the data). This ensures each day uses a different one of the 92 partitions; except it doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE records(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dt DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
PARTITION BY HASH((MOD(DAYOFYEAR(dt), 92) + 92))
PARTITIONS 92;
```

The problem with the above snippet is that the column used in the hash expression has to be a unique key within the table.

How can I fix this so that I have ninety(ish) rotating partitions based on each day's records?

If I simply add the `dt` column to primary key, it seems to hit all the partitions if a select a date range, which is not what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that to partition on a date field and query by range you must either use `YEAR()` or `TO_DAYS()` in the partition expression.

Partitioning like this works as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE `alert` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eventId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `occurred` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(occurred))
(PARTITION 28_06 VALUES LESS THAN (735413) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 29_06 VALUES LESS THAN (735414) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 30_06 VALUES LESS THAN (735415) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 01_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735416) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 02_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735417) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 03_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735418) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 04_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735419) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 05_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735420) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 06_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735421) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 07_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735422) ENGINE = InnoDB) */

mysql> explain partitions SELECT * FROM alert WHERE occurred >= '2013-07-02' and occurred <= '2013-07-04';
+----+-------------+-------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | alert | 02_07,03_07,04_07 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Then you need to manage dropping and creating of the partition yourself.

Comment: SO this means if i need to collect 30, 60,90 days old records then i need to specify the **to_days_value  -90** and so on, every month to keep collecting the 30 days old records, every time we alter the partition and create new ones. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is that you can't define a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key on a partitioned table, if all the columns in the key are not included in the hash function.

One possible "fix" would be to remove the "`PRIMARY`" keyword from the KEY definition.

The problem is that MySQL has to enforce uniqueness when you declare a key to be UNIQUE or PRIMARY. And in order to enforce that, MySQL needs to be able to check whether the key value already exists.  Instead of checking every partition, MySQL uses the partitioning function to determine the partition where a particular key would be found.